# How to Add and Edit Events through Generic handler in Kendo UI Scheduler?

Tags: c#, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-scheduler

I want to add the events from Kendo UI Scheduler to the Database through a Generic Handler How Can I do So? and how to get the event fields and pass them to the handler?
I have Populated the events in the scheduler through the following code successfully but i can`t figure out how to Add new events and Update or delete them...

```
dataSource: {

    transport:
    {
        read:
        {
            url: "../Handler.ashx",
            dataType: "json",
            //contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

        },
        update: {
            url: "http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/meetings/update",
            dataType: "jsonp"
        },
        create: {
            url: "http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/meetings/create",
            dataType: "jsonp"
        },
        destroy: {
            url: "http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/meetings/destroy",
            dataType: "jsonp"
        },

        parameterMap: function (options, operation) {
            if (operation !== "read" && options.models) {
                return { models: kendo.stringify(options.models) };
            }
        }
    }, schema: {
        model: {
            id: "id",
            fields: {
                id: { from: "id", type: "number" },
                title: { field: "title", defaultValue: "No title", validation: { required: true } },
                start: { type: "date", field: "start" },
                end: { type: "date", field: "end" },

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

These methods are what you want to change and point to ASHX files or MVC Methods (if using MVC of course):

**Web Forms**

```
update: {
        url: "http://localhost:30000/update.ashx",
        dataType: "jsonp"
    },
create: {
        url: "http://localhost:30000/create.ashx",
        dataType: "jsonp"
    },
destroy: {
        url: "http://localhost:30000/destroy.ashx",
        dataType: "jsonp"
    },
```

**MVC**

```
update: {
        url: "http://localhost:30000/home/update",
        dataType: "jsonp"
    },
create: {
        url: "http://localhost:30000/home/create",
        dataType: "jsonp"
    },
destroy: {
        url: "http://localhost:30000/home/destroy",
        dataType: "jsonp"
    },
```

And from your example, it looks like the event fields coming across would be:

id, title, start, end

The Kendo UI Scheduler code will attempt to post JSON data to those Urls depending on what you are trying to do.  If you are using Firebug (in Firefox) or Fiddler2, you can inspect the data that is getting posted as well as use your IDE (like Visual Studio, Eclipse, etc.) to step through the receiving server-side code.

I have been all over this Scheduler (though from the ASP.NET MVC wrapper version), and here's my main post about that: [Binding a DropDownList in Kendo Scheduler Custom Template (ASP.NET MVC Wrapper version)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22235835/binding-a-dropdownlist-in-kendo-scheduler-custom-template-asp-net-mvc-wrapper-v)  There is some more info that I broke down in trying to figure out the Scheduler like you are doing. Some of it may be useful like for constructing the server-side code to receive the data.

Here's an example in MVC: http://www.telerik.com/support/code-library/custom-editor-9fd60fca3c02