# Kendo UI - Scheduler - Add Event

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I'm working with Kendo UI's Scheduler widget. 
I need to modify the "Add Event" window that is triggered when you click on a calendar day.

I can not find out where this window is being called from, or where these fields are being defined. I need to update this. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

The code I am using to generate the Sceduler widget is as follows:

```
<div id="example">
    <div id="team-schedule">
        <div id="People">
             <input checked type="checkbox" id="Country" value="1" disabled="disabled">
             <input checked type="checkbox" id="Region" value="2">
             <input type="checkbox" id="District" value="3">
             <input type="checkbox" id="WorkUnit" value="4">
             <input type="checkbox" id="Classifier" value="5">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="Schedule" class="calendars"></div>
</div>
<script>
    $("#Schedule").kendoScheduler({
  date: new Date("2013/6/6"), // The current date of the scheduler
  views: [

           "month",
             { type: "month", selected: true },
           "week",
            "day"
  ],
  dataSource: [ // The kendo.data.SchedulerDataSource configuration
    // First scheduler event
    {
      id: 1, // Unique identifier. Needed for editing.
      start: new Date("2013/6/6 08:00 AM"), // Start of the event
      end: new Date("2013/6/6 09:00 AM"), // End of the event
      title: "Classification" // Title of the event
    }
  ]
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to investigate the Scheduler Editor Template.  [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22235835/binding-a-dropdownlist-in-kendo-scheduler-custom-template-asp-net-mvc-wrapper-v) is a detailed version (albeit it's the MVC wrapper version, but the Kendo template is defined similarly without the Razor code by the **<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="schedulerTemplate">** block.  For the HTML5/JS version, you'll just define the fields as you normally would with **<input>** fields.

The fields that get passed to the Event window are defined in Schema for HTML5/JS

**Here are the links to the Scheduler custom editor for Kendo UI (Telerik's Code Library):**

- [HTML5/JS Version](http://www.telerik.com/support/code-library/custom-editor)
- [ASP.NET MVC Version](http://www.telerik.com/support/code-library/custom-editor-9fd60fca3c02) (in case someone is looking for the MVC version)

There is a complete [blog post](http://www.jwc3.net/2014/05/kendo-ui-scheduler-with-aspnet-mvc-and.html) for using the Scheduler, but it's in the ASP.NET MVC version.  You can still follow along as it draws correlations to the HTML5/JS version in the walk-through.